# .net library to read pdf on Windows CE

Tags: .net, pdf, compact-framework, windows-ce

is there any .net library to make small app to read pdf on Windows CE ?

thanks

Comment: Pdfsharp or Itextsharp can do it for you...

Answer (score -1):

Hai william,

> NetXtreme PDF is a .NET library with the capability to produce Adobe PDF files. It features a full-fledged object model for the easy creation of PDF files from any .NET language, providing complete control over the positioning of the elements in a PDF document. It does not use any external libraries and is built from scratch in C#. It can be used on the server-side (ASP.NET or any other environment) or with Windows Forms / WPF applications. The usage is common for both environments, except for the part where the created document is saved to disk or stream in the case of Windows Forms / WPF applications, and streamed to the client browser in the case of ASP.NET applications. Note that there are no temporary documents saved on the server in an ASP.NET application. NetXtreme PDF supports many features for creating a PDF document including drawing text, images, tables and other shapes. The generated PDF document can also be protected using 40 Bit and 128 Bit encryption.

Answer (score -1):

Use iTextSharp.  It's free and you only need the "itextsharp.dll".

http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/

Here is a simple function for reading the text out of a PDF.

```
Public Shared Function GetTextFromPDF(PdfFileName As String) As String
    Dim oReader As New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(PdfFileName)

    Dim sOut = ""

    For i = 1 To oReader.NumberOfPages
        Dim its As New iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy

        sOut &= iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(oReader, i, its)
    Next

    Return sOut
End Function
```